# How can I access the UniqueId of a folder using CSOM against Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, csom

Using the following code with CSOM 16.1 against SharePoint Online I am able to retrieve a list of folders:

```
var folderList = string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentRelativeUrl)
? sharePointContext.Web.Folders
: sharePointContext.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(parentRelativeUrl).Folders;

sharePointContext.Load(folderList, items => items.Include(
item => item.Folders, 
item => item.Files,
item => item.Name, 
item => item.ServerRelativeUrl, 
item => item.Properties, 
item => item.UniqueId));

sharePointContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

When running against a 2013 on premise version of SharePoint my stumbling block seems to be around the UniqueId field. The error I am getting is:

> Field or property "UniqueId" does not exist.

I then tried downgrading my CSOM version to 2013, and I could see that the Folder class doesn't contain the UniqueId field.

Is there a way to retrieve this field in 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your current situation i recommend you to check out the [ClientObject.Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee541935(v=office.15).aspx) Property, which is available for SharePoint 2013. It does not need to be retrieved, as it is an internal property, which will be composed by the API. For my test it contained the following values:

```
Console.WriteLine(folder.Path);
"GUID|GUID:site:GUID:web:GUID:folder:GUIDYOUNEED"
```

The 'GUIDYOUNEED' is equal to the UniqueId of the folder.

Comment: Great thanks this seems to work allowing me to access the unique Id on both SP online and 2013 using CSOM 16.1. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Item.Id would help you.. You can only choose the variables which are available. The moment you type item. the help will give you list of operations and variable associated to item, you have to choose "id" to get the uniqueId of the item
to get the Id of the list or document library you can use the method "GetListByTitle".

```
 List doc = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
        clientContext.Load(doc);
clientContent.ExecuteQuery();
```

doc.id will give you the unique id of the document library.